# ASP.NET Core 6 Dependency injection in controller return System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I'm trying to develop a Web API project with ASP.NET Core 6, but I get this error, there seems to be an error in the dependency injection, but I haven't found this:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'api.Interface.IUsersService' while attempting to activate 'api.Controllers.UsersController'.
>
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
> at lambda_method3(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

`Startup.cs` :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
       string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
       services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => options.UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString)));
       services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("ApiCorsPolicy", build =>
        {
            build.WithOrigins("http://localhost:8080")
                 .AllowAnyMethod()
                 .AllowAnyHeader();
        }));
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddScoped<IJwtUtils, JwtUtils>();
        services.AddScoped<IUsersService, UsersService>();
        services.AddScoped<IQrcodesService, QrcodesService>();
        services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));

        services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
        });
}
```

`IUsersService.cs`:

```
using api.Response;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace api.Interface
{
    public interface IUsersService
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

`UsersService.cs`:

```
using api.Authorization;
using api.Helpers;
using api.Interface;
using api.Response;
using AutoMapper;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using BCryptNet = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt;

namespace api.Services
{
    public class UsersService : IUsersService
    {
        private DataContext _context;
        private IJwtUtils _jwtUtils;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public UsersService(
            DataContext context,
            IJwtUtils jwtUtils,
            IMapper mapper)
        {
            _context = context;
            _jwtUtils = jwtUtils;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

`UsersController.cs`:

```
using api.Helpers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using api.Response;
using api.Authorization;
using api.Interface;

namespace api.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class UsersController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IUsersService _userService;
        private readonly AppSettings _appSettings;

        public UsersController(
            IUsersService userService,
            IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
        {
            _userService = userService;
            _appSettings = appSettings.Value;
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

`DataContext.cs`:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using api.Response;
using BCryptNet = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt;
using api.Authorization;

namespace api.Helpers
{
    public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DataContext() { }

        public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options) { }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<QRcode> QRcodes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Giustification> Giustifications  { get; set; }
       
        // ...
    }
}
```

`JwtUtils.js`:

```
public class JwtUtils : IJwtUtils
{
    private readonly AppSettings _appSettings;

    public JwtUtils(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
    {
        _appSettings = appSettings.Value;
    }
           //...
}
```

I'm using pomelo 6.0.1 with mysql '8.0.27' and .NET 6.

Comment: You didn't post UsersController

Comment: i fixed it, sorry

Comment: What about JwtUtils? Does it have all the dependencies it needs? The problem with these errors is that usually, you don't get exactly what's wrong. It says that it failed to initialize something but the root cause might be the dependency of the class you are trying to initialize. Or even dependency of the dependency.

Comment: Is there any inner exception at all?

Comment: @phuzi I have not found any other exceptions

Comment: What dependencies does `JwtUtils` have? Are they all registered/satisfied?

Comment: i edited the question with dependecies of JwtUtils.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, the project started with .net 5 and then migrated to 6.
The new version has changed file `Program.cs`

My new `Program.cs`

```
using api;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var startup = new Startup(builder.Configuration);


startup.ConfigureServices(builder.Services);

var app = builder.Build();

startup.Configure(app, app.Environment);

app.Run();
```

for more information on how to migrate the project :  [Migrate from ASP.NET Core 5.0 to 6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)
I want to thank everyone for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think this
 *services.Configure(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));*
line need to be executed before
services.AddScoped<IJwtUtils, JwtUtils>();

Comment: same result, nothing has changed